# EF Complex relationship definition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relationship

I have defined a trading relationship between 2 companies like this ...

```
public class TradingRelationship
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Supplier")]
    public int SupplierCompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Buyer")]
    public int BuyerCompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Supplier { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

... and a company of course has a relationship to many trading relationships like this ...

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TradingRelationship> TradingRelationships { get; set; }
}
```

... my problem is that when EF generates the table I not only get the buyer and supplier ids but an additional column named Company_Id on the trading relationship table for some reason.

Can anyone tell me how to define this relationship in such a way that I don't have the extra column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have one mistake: when you define TradingRelationships propery in Company you wanted to map it to both properties in TradingRelationship class: Supplier and Buyer and EF confused. I assume that this solution will help you:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Supplier ")]
    public virtual ICollection<TradingRelationship> TradingRelationshipsSupplier  { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Buyer ")]
    public virtual ICollection<TradingRelationship> TradingRelationshipsBuyer  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I didn't realise EF couldn't map the way I was going ... figured it made sense froma SQL point of view so EF could figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be, that the `ICollection<TradingRelationship>` reference is not part of your model. When you remove this line in your `Company` model:

```
public virtual ICollection<TradingRelationship> TradingRelationships { get; set; }
```

Your database should be as you wish. And if you want to get all `TradingRelationships` refer to a `Company`, you could use Linq:

```
TradingRelationships.Where(t => t.Supplier == company || t.Buyer == company)
```